# How can I use a Selenium type method?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a [JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) page with an input text field.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchInput"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I wrote a Selenium test case that verifies that the search input text is present.

```
public class UIRecipeListTest extends SeleneseTestBase {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(
                        new FirefoxBinary(
                            new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox 3.6\\firefox.exe")),
                        new FirefoxProfile()
                    );

        String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/RecipeProject/";
        selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShowRecipes() {
        verifyTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("searchText"));
        selenium.type("searchText", "salt");
    }
}
```

The `verifyTrue` test returns `true`. However, the `selenium.type` test failed with this error:

> ```
> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Element searchText not found
> ```

What should I do to make the test work?

Comment: As the exception say, it not getting that text in that search field.

Comment: @smit : I think the exception means that selenium could not find an input text with an id of searchText. However, the verify true proved that the element with that id exist.

Comment: may be I am wrong. I just played with selenium as fun. However may be you should wait for that textfield.

Comment: As is written [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/SeleneseTestBase.html#verifyTrue%28boolean%29), the `verifyTrue()` method fails at the end of the tests, not immediatelly. Use `assertTrue()` and tell us what you see.

Comment: If this question was answered - please accept an answer so this question can be closed, if you are having seperate issues with Selenium with firefox, please start a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first parameter needs to be a selector. `searchText` isn't a valid CSS or XPath selector.

You would use something like `selenium.type("css=input#searchText", "salt");`.

I also wanted to point out that you seem to be going between two versions of Selenium.

`selenium.type(String,String)` is from the Selenium 1 API. You should keep to the 1 version, and if it's going to be Selenium 2, you need to do something like,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("searchText"))
```

and use

```
element.sendKeys("salt");
```

Source: *[Selenium API type(String,String)](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#type%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)*

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have suspicion that my firefox is not working properly. I tried different combination of selectors and none of them are working.